# Issue when deploying with firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, twitter-bootstrap, indexing

I'm having an issue deploying with firebase. I have an HTML/CSS/Javascript portfolio that I'm trying to deploy. It also uses Bootstrap. When I run "npm run build", I keep getting this error. It has something to do with the bootstrap/JS script tag. I did "npm run build" without any JS script tags and my project deployed with no issues. But for some reason there's an issue when deploying with JS. It doesn't build my JS folder or the index.html file into my dist folder. I've checked the filename mentioned (node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js) and there's nothing wrong there. Here is the error I get after "npm run build":

```
    throw new JS_Parse_Error(message, filename, line, col, pos);
    ^
JS_Parse_Error [SyntaxError]: Unexpected token: punc ([)
    at JS_Parse_Error.get (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/alexiswinters/Desktop/Personal-Portfolio/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:27:1), <anonymous>:86:23)
    at formatError (node:internal/util/inspect:1168:38)
    at formatRaw (node:internal/util/inspect:938:14)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:793:10)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:340:10)
    at afterInspector (node:internal/errors:781:14) {
  filename: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  line: 6,
  col: 357,
  pos: 594
}
```

Comment: What "tags" are you referring to? Please see [ask], then revise to show us some code.